# SF Chat Android SDK v4.2.2 (latest) still contains legacy support libraries

Tags: mobilesdk, android, chat, salesforce-sdk-android

The [latest available version](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ServiceSDK-Android/releases) of the SF Chat Android SDK (`com.salesforce.service:chat-ui:4.2.2`) has not been migrated to AndroidX yet (after 3 years).

It still depends on:

- `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`
- `com.android.support:design:28.0.0`
- `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3`
- `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3`

Does anyone know whether SF has plans to migrate it to AndroidX?
At the moment, it is the only dependency preventing us from disabling Jetifier.

Comment: As this is all about versions and roadmap - have you tried asking this question [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F9300000001qepCAA?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC)? (I'm happy to volunteer in case you lack access.) These groups are read by many SF employees...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll repost it there.

Answer (score 0):

We just got an answer via our account manager:

> No plans at the moment to migrate to androidx

Which is sad and shameful...

So if you have to depend on this non-properly maintain closed-source **PAID** SalesForce SDK remember that you have to keep `jetifier` enabled and include `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui` dependency, as `jetifier` [will map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) some of the legacy support classes (e.g. `android.support.v4.widget.Space`) to the corresponding ones in this package (of course, this is not mentioned in their [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.service_sdk_android.meta/service_sdk_android/android_sdk_prereqs.htm#android_sdk_prereq)).